# c# if-else within catch statement

Tags: c#, exception, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to write a single if-else block within a catch method, but when I get the error that 'not all code paths return type int.'

Essentially, I'm writing a method that saves a UserName and Password to a Sql CE database, and I want to test for one specific error. (UserName already exists.) The UserName column is unique, so it will reliably throw a SqlCeException with NativeError = 25016. I want to display that with an error message, otherwise handle other exceptions in a more generic way.

My code is:

```
  try
  {
    //insert command  (This is where the duplicate column error is thrown)
    //Select @@Identity & Return it
  }
  catch (SqlCeException ex)
  {
   if (ex.NativeError == 25016)
        MessageBox.Show("Username already in use."); 
   else
     //whatever
  }
```

I've tried showing a different, more generic message and get the no return error. 
I've tried throwing a new exception and catching it in another block. Same error.
I've tried returning -1 (as a sort of flag value). Same error.

There doesn't appear to be a more specific error than SqlCeException for this specific case (Though I ma have just failed me debug-fu).

Any creative work-arounds? 
Worst case, I'll write a method that checks the DB for duplicate usernames before calling this method.

Comment: The error message you mention is about the return value of the function, and none of that is shown in the code you have shared.

Comment: After the insert, I select the @@identity of the table I inserted to, then return it. 
The only thing I've found to shut up the error is putting "throw ex;" and nothing else within the catch block. 
I'm just a student, and not great at Try-Catch. Any ideas?

Comment: The other folks who have answered have gotten the core of it--you need a return value even when the catch-clause is invoked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your method returns an `int`. You need to return a value of type `int` from your catch block.

```
  try
  {
    //insert command  (This is where the duplicate column error is thrown)
    //Select @@Identity & Return it
  }
  catch (SqlCeException ex)
  {
   if (ex.NativeError == 25016)
        MessageBox.Show("Username already in use."); 
   else
   {
     //whatever  
   }
   return -1;
  }
```

Comment: +1. (Edited answer to add curly braces in else - while saving 2 bytes of source code is very important, comments are not considered statement - so return was in else part only).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Thanks for making it clearer. I assumed the reader would understand that `// whatever` represents the `else` block. Better to err on unmistakable.

Comment: Yeah, I did this one, except I put the return -1 after the if block, but inside the catch. I think I was misunderstanding the problem somehow..

I know it's bad form, but would anyone mind upvoting the question a few times? I lack the karma points to upvote people who were helpful. I just need 15.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your function returns an `int` value.

In your `try` block you get and return an integer value. That's fine.

In the `catch` block you do not mention returning an integer. This is the problem.

So when the function takes the exception path, it doesn't have an integer to pass back causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole function need to return value. Since you are eating exception in try-cathc you need to have return of some sort at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Use finally block to return int:

```
 try
  {
    //insert command  (This is where the duplicate column error is thrown)
    //Select @@Identity & Return it       
  }
  catch (SqlCeException ex)
  {
   if (ex.NativeError == 25016)
        MessageBox.Show("Username already in use."); 
   else
     //whatever
  }
  finally
  {
    return -1;
  }
```

If try block return Identity value then finally `return -1` will not effect. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715198/will-finally-blocks-be-executed-if-returning-from-try-or-catch-blocks-in-c-if)

Comment: I is not so good. If your code works properly, it also returns -1 against right value.

Comment: any reason? if code works perfectly it will assign value to ValueToReturn and that will be return back

Comment: You are right if we return in try block, but I'm not sure that after try-catch there is no anything else.